# How to select weekday / hour in pandas when doing iteration

Tags: python, pandas

I'm filtering a dataframe by hour and weekday:

```
if type == 'daily':
    hour = data.index.hour
    day = data.index.weekday
    selector = ((hour != 17)) | ((day!=5) & (day!=6))
    data = data[selector]

if type == 'weekly':
    day = data.index.weekday
    selector = ((day!=5) & (day!=6))
    data = data[selector]
```

Then I'm using a for where I need to write some conditional according to the weekday/hour and the row.index doesn't have any information. What can I do in this case ?

I need to do something like (this it won't work since row.index doesn't have weekday or hour info):

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    if type == 'weekly' & row.index.weekday == 1 & row.index.hour == 0 & row.index.min == 0 | \
            type == 'daily' & row.index.hour == 18 & row.index.min == 0:
```

Thx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is not the most elegant way, but you could create your variables in columns:

```
df['Hour'] = df.index.hour
```

If you need a min or a max based on those variables, you could create another column and use rolling_min or rolling type formulas.

Once you have your columns, you can iterate as you please with iteration you suggested.

There's info about the [index properties here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/api.html#properties)

Comment: Thx, that's a way to do it, i will code it to see how it goes.